# why can't I access data within this ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made the below code to learn Angular. It uses the input entered by user to make an ajax request for a json file that contains a list of object, then print that list to the user.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('myController', function($http) {
            var ctlr = this;
            ctlr.param = "";
            ctlr.responses = [];

            this.makeQuery = function() {
                $http.get('http://localhost:8080?p=' + ctlr.param))
                .then(function(data) {
                        ctlr.response = data; // data -> [{key1: value1,...},...]
                });
            };
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController as mc">
        <input type="text" ng-model="mc.param">
        <input type="submit" ng-click="mc.makeQuery()" value="Submit">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="res in responses">
                <span>{{res.key1}}, {{res.key2}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this code in Chrome, I see a list of empty bullet points. Chrome DevTools shows the json file returned as expected so I know `ctlr.param` works. However the list has empty bullet points so `ng-repeat` does not work correctly. It seems I cannot access `cltr.responses` properly. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `responses` object is binded to `this` and not to `$scope` as you are using [controller as](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) 
You should use `mc.responses` instead of `responses`

```
<li ng-repeat="res in mc.responses">
     <span>{{res.key1}}, {{res.key2}}</span>
</li>
```

You can read more from [johnpapa](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/) style

Comment: Please share `console.log(responses);`

Comment: I found out there are 2 causes. One is the binding of `responses`. The other is that `$http.get` returns a string while the code expects a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Above solution is right but  as i checked the complete code and found that there is one  mistake. 
In script code

`ctlr.response = data; // data -> [{key1: value1,...},...]` should be

`ctlr.responses = data; // data -> [{key1: value1,...},...]`